# Problem with buttons addeventlisteners in Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, button, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a calendar, i've coded a long time ago in another langage but my company website is actually in javascript and HTML, so it is what is it.

I'm having a pretty basic problem I think(although I can't solve it). I'm trying to create buttons in the header of my calendar, which itselfs appear in a pop-up in said page. I managed to make the buttons appear after some try and errors...but the event listeners I created don't seem to work at all!

I tried some debugging already as you will see in the code, some is //

Here for starters is where I create the ''header'' with the buttons (arrows)

```
function createCalendarHeader() {
  const calendarHeader = document.createElement('div');
  calendarHeader.classList.add('calendar-header');


  // Add the month display
  const monthDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  calendarHeader.appendChild(monthDisplay);

  // Add previous month arrow button
  prevMonthButton = document.createElement('button');
  prevMonthButton.innerHTML = '&lt;';
  prevMonthButton.addEventListener('click', () => { //<-- Here are the event listeners.
    showPreviousMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
    updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
  });


  calendarHeader.appendChild(prevMonthButton);

  // Add next month arrow button
  nextMonthButton = document.createElement('button');
  nextMonthButton.innerHTML = '&gt;';
  nextMonthButton.addEventListener('click', () => { //<-- Here are the event listeners.
    showNextMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
    updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
    console.log('Button next clicked');
  });

  console.log('Buttons created');

  calendarHeader.appendChild(nextMonthButton);

  return {
    calendarHeader,
    monthDisplay,
    prevMonthButton,
    nextMonthButton
  };
}
```

After, I try to wrap it all up with the calendar, and use this function to call the pop-up in the HTML, I keep thinking this might be where it screws it up...:

```
function showSkiDetails(skiId) {
  const selectedSki = skiInventory.find((ski) => ski.id === skiId);

  // Create a fake pop-up container
  const fakePopup = document.createElement('div');
  fakePopup.classList.add('fake-popup');

  // Create a calendar container
  const calendarContainer = createCalendarContainer();

  // Create a calendar header
  const { calendarHeader, monthDisplay, prevMonthButton, nextMonthButton } = createCalendarHeader();

  // Append the header to the container
  calendarContainer.appendChild(calendarHeader);

  // Add days to the calendar
  updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);

  // Create a container for the header and buttons
  const headerButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
  headerButtonContainer.classList.add('header-button-container');

  // Append the buttons and header to the container
  headerButtonContainer.appendChild(prevMonthButton);
  headerButtonContainer.appendChild(monthDisplay);
  headerButtonContainer.appendChild(nextMonthButton);

  // Populate the fake pop-up with ski details and calendar
  fakePopup.innerHTML = `
    <div class="popup-content">
      <span class="close" onclick="closeFakePopup()">&times;</span>
      <h2>${selectedSki.model}</h2>
      <p>Status: ${selectedSki.status}</p>
      <p>Location: ${selectedSki.location}</p>
      <div class="calendar-container">${headerButtonContainer.outerHTML}${calendarContainer.outerHTML}</div>
    </div>
  `;

  // Append the fake pop-up to the body
  document.body.appendChild(fakePopup);
        
}
```

We then make the pop up appear in the HTML simply :

I tried adding a bunch of logs, and the none of the logs in the event listeners worked, although everything else seems to be getting called and created properly...

Thanks for the help!

The HTML and CSS are already in full, here is the full javascript so you can try the ''program'':

**Code Snippet**

```js
const skiInventory = [
    { id: 1, model: 'Ski Model 1', status: 'available', location: 'Shop A' },
    { id: 2, model: 'Ski Model 2', status: 'rented', location: 'Customer X' },
    { id: 3, model: 'Ski Model 3', status: 'available', location: 'Shop A' },
   
    // ... add more ski data as needed
];

// Function to render the inventory grid
function renderInventory() {
    const inventoryGrid = document.getElementById('inventory-grid');
    inventoryGrid.innerHTML = ''; 
  // Clear previous content

    skiInventory.forEach(ski => {
        const skiCard = document.createElement('div');
        skiCard.classList.add('ski-card');
        skiCard.innerHTML = `
            <p>${ski.model}</p>
            <p>Status: ${ski.status}</p>
            <button onclick="showSkiDetails(${ski.id})">Details</button>
        `;
        inventoryGrid.appendChild(skiCard);
    });
}



 //Début de la création du calendrier
  let currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  
 
  function createCalendarContainer() {
      const calendarContainer = document.createElement('div');
      calendarContainer.classList.add('calendar');
    return calendarContainer;
  }

  function createCalendarHeader() {
        const calendarHeader = document.createElement('div');
        calendarHeader.classList.add('calendar-header');


        // Add the month display
        const monthDisplay = document.createElement('div');
        calendarHeader.appendChild(monthDisplay);

      // Add previous month arrow button
        prevMonthButton = document.createElement('button');
        prevMonthButton.innerHTML = '&lt;';
        prevMonthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          showPreviousMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay); 
          updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
       });

    
       calendarHeader.appendChild(prevMonthButton);

        // Add next month arrow button
        nextMonthButton = document.createElement('button');
        nextMonthButton.innerHTML = '&gt;';
        nextMonthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          showNextMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay); 
          updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
        console.log('Boutons next clicked');
        });
        console.log('Boutons créer');
        calendarHeader.appendChild(nextMonthButton);

  return { calendarHeader, monthDisplay, prevMonthButton, nextMonthButton };
}


  //Fonction qui fait apparaitre la fênetre avec le calendrier,
  function showSkiDetails(skiId) {
      const selectedSki = skiInventory.find((ski) => ski.id === skiId);

      // Create a fake pop-up container
      const fakePopup = document.createElement('div');
      fakePopup.classList.add('fake-popup');

      // Create a calendar container
      const calendarContainer = createCalendarContainer();

      // Create a calendar header
      const { calendarHeader, monthDisplay, prevMonthButton, nextMonthButton } = createCalendarHeader();

      // Append the header to the container
      calendarContainer.appendChild(calendarHeader);

      // Add days to the calendar
      updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);

      // Create a container for the header and buttons
      const headerButtonContainer = document.createElement('div');
      headerButtonContainer.classList.add('header-button-container');

      // Append the buttons and header to the container
      headerButtonContainer.appendChild(prevMonthButton);
      headerButtonContainer.appendChild(monthDisplay);
      headerButtonContainer.appendChild(nextMonthButton);

      // Populate the fake pop-up with ski details and calendar
      fakePopup.innerHTML = `
        <div class="popup-content">
          <span class="close" onclick="closeFakePopup()">&times;</span>
          <h2>${selectedSki.model}</h2>
          <p>Status: ${selectedSki.status}</p>
          <p>Location: ${selectedSki.location}</p>
          <div class="calendar-container">${headerButtonContainer.outerHTML}${calendarContainer.outerHTML}</div>
        </div>
      `;

      // Append the fake pop-up to the body
      document.body.appendChild(fakePopup);
        
}

  function onCalendarDayClick(day) {
    // Handle the calendar day click event
    console.log('Selected day:', day);
    // You can add your logic here, such as updating the selected date in your application.
  }

  function showPreviousMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay) {
    // Show the previous month
    currentMonth -= 1;
    if (currentMonth < 0) {
      currentMonth = 11;
      currentYear -= 1;
    }

    updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
  }

  function showNextMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay) {
    // Show the next month
    currentMonth += 1;
    if (currentMonth > 11) {
      currentMonth = 0;
      currentYear += 1;
    }
    console.log(currentMonth)
    updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
  }

  function updateCalendar(calendarContainer, monthDisplay) {
  // Update the calendar with the new month and year
  calendarContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the existing calendar
  console.log('update calendar');
  // Add days of the week
  const daysOfWeek = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  daysOfWeek.forEach((day) => {
    const dayOfWeek = document.createElement('div');
    dayOfWeek.classList.add('calendar-day', 'header-day');
    dayOfWeek.textContent = day;
    calendarContainer.appendChild(dayOfWeek);
  });

  // Add the month display
  monthDisplay.textContent = `${getMonthName(currentMonth)} ${currentYear}`;

  // Get the first day of the month
  const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1).getDay();

  // Add days to the calendar
  const daysInMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate();

  for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth + firstDayOfMonth; i++) {
    const calendarDay = document.createElement('div');
    calendarDay.classList.add('calendar-day');

    if (i > firstDayOfMonth) {
      const dayOfMonth = i - firstDayOfMonth;
      calendarDay.textContent = dayOfMonth;
      calendarDay.addEventListener('click', () => onCalendarDayClick(dayOfMonth));
    }

    calendarContainer.appendChild(calendarDay);
  }
}

  function getMonthName(monthIndex) {
    const monthNames = [
      'January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
      'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
      'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
    ];
    return monthNames[monthIndex];
  }
// Function to close the fake pop-up
function closeFakePopup() {
    const fakePopup = document.querySelector('.fake-popup');
    fakePopup.parentNode.removeChild(fakePopup);
}

// Function to handle the check-out process
function checkOut(skiId) {
    // Implement logic to update the status of the selected ski to 'rented'
    renderInventory(); // Refresh the inventory grid
}

// Function to handle the check-in process
function checkIn(skiId) {
    // Implement logic to update the status of the selected ski to 'available'
    renderInventory(); // Refresh the inventory grid
}

// Initial rendering of the inventory
renderInventory();
```

```css
#inventory-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
}

.ski-card {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.ski-card p {
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margins for <p> elements */
}

.ski-card button {
    margin-top: auto; /* Push the button to the bottom of the card */
}

.fake-popup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.popup-content {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  .calendar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    gap: 5px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .calendar-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .calendar-day {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .calendar-day:hover {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="inventory-grid"></div>
<div id="ski-details"></div>
```

Comment: Would you be able to attach the relevant CSS to the question as well? Being able to see what the calendar looks like would greatly help the problem solving experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: "after some errors" -- what errors? Please add these details to the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think the corrections/edits should help you all help me :)

Comment: The problem appears to be in your `showSkiDetails` method.  You create calendar object with events, but then inject it into the dialog as html (outerHTML).  Doing this removes all the event listeners that were previously added.  To fix this, you will need to append the calendar object after the modal is created or else add the listeners after it is created.

Comment: hi @Yogi !! 
Thanks a lot for the input, I feel like this is the case too, and wasn't certain about how to go on adding the listeners after it is created! 

Where should I do this to make sure everything is created?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing the button eventListeners with the following:

```
prevMonthButton.onclick = () => showPreviousMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
nextMonthButton.onclick = () => showNextMonth(calendarContainer, monthDisplay);
```

Adding these onclick attributes does the same thing functionally, but adds the code to the button element itself. This way, you can see if the issue is with the buttons, with the functions they are calling, or something else entirely.

(You also don't need to call `updateCalendar()` for either of these buttons since the function gets called within both `showPreviousMonth()` and `showNextMonth()`)

This may still fire errors within your code since I see a few spots you most likely would still want to fix, but this should help solve the specific issue you're requesting.

Comment: Hi Nick! 
Thanks a lot for the answer, I tried a quickfix by simply changing the eventlisteners, and they still do nothing. 
I think Yogi has a part of the answer at least, me appending the buttons as html seems to be removing all listeners onto them! 

Im trying to figure out if i'm approaching this in the wrong way, or if I simply need to declare the events later on/somwhere else! 

Thanks again to this community, this is my first question and clearly it's not so easy to be concise :)

Comment: I would say that my two cents would be to build the HTML structure within the HTML first, then hide and display the HTML with JavaScript and CSS. You can go about the way you are currently though so definitely do what works best for you.

Comment: I know i've been building nothing in the HTML basically...